# Can I use my D drive to install a software which has a recommended path C:\ user \ AppData \ Roaming

Tags: installation, drive, appdata, roaming

I have 2 drives C and D. C is 128 GB SSD and D is 1 TB HDD. Win 10 is installed on my C drive. As far as I know, I can use my D drive to install programs like Adobe, Office, Games... However, some programs want to be installed my AppData folder. In the installation process, destination location is shown as my app data roaming folder for these programs. If I change the destination folder as any folder in my D drive, will the program be affected badly when I use it?

For example, I want to install telegram rn and the setup wizard recommends me to install it to AppData folder in my C drive.

Answer (score 0):

This question Appears to belong to [Superuser](http://superuser.com), but for the answer:
It is technically 'fine', to install to the C drive, from the D drive (if you have some of the files on the D drive, too), but remember that to run the program, you must have the D drive in!
I'd recommend getting all the files in the D drive, because there is a possibility of corruption, if you keep it on two Drives.

Comment: I understand that it's hard to refrain from answering, but by doing this you stimulate offtopic questions on SO.

Comment: I guess I do, though it is fairly rare (for me) to find Questions like this, however.